# Splunk HTTP Event Collector Log4j2 Spring boot unable to send data to Splunk cloud

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2, splunk

I have followed all the tutorials on youtube and I have read all the available documentation on Splunk Cloud HEC setup in Log4j2 Spring boot.

Below is my log4j2-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="LoggingTesting" packages="">
    <Appenders>


                <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                    <PatternLayout
                            pattern="event:{%style{%d{ISO8601}} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{10}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable}" />
                </Console>
        <SplunkHttp
                name="splunkhttp"
                url="https://prd-p-vy06a.splunkcloud.com:8088/services/collector/event"
                token="TOKEN********************"
                host="wa-blog-service"
                index="wa_blog_service_dev_index"

                sourcetype="_json"
                disableCertificateValidation="true" >
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="event:{%style{%d{ISO8601}} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{10}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable}" />
        </SplunkHttp>

        <File name="wa-blog-application" fileName="logs/waBlogApplication.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>




    <Loggers>
        <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
        <Root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="wa-blog-application"/>
               <AppenderRef ref="console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="splunkhttp" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is my POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.worldastrologers</groupId>
    <artifactId>blog</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>wa-qa-service</name>
    <description>WorldAstrologers Service.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>splunk-artifactory</id>
            <name>Splunk Releases</name>
            <url>https://splunk.jfrog.io/splunk/ext-releases-local</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.splunk.logging/splunk-library-javalogging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>wa-blog-service</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

What am I missing ???

I can't see data on my Splunk cloud account. I have checked all the indices.
I am able to see data in Splunk cloud when I send a request from Postman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL in the  log4j2-spring.xml file is incorrect.
The URL should be

```
url="https://prd-p-vy06a.splunkcloud.com:8088"
```